# How to Iterate over four arrays one by one and printing them in django template?

Tags: django, templates, filter

I am going to print four array values simultaneously in django template . like this 
the four arrays are of equal length ,they are header_list , domain_list , domain_data , dom

```
for i in range(10):
      print headerlist[i]
      print domain_list[i]
      print domain_data[i]
      print dom[i]
```

how to acheive these in django template .

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
{% for i in my_range %}
    {{ headerlist|slice:i }}
    {{ domain_list|slice:i }}
    {{ domain_data|slice:i }}
    {{ dom|slice:i }}
{% endfor %}
```

`my_range` will have to be passed as variable to the template render function

Comment: How to write a template rendering function .
`from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='times')
def times(number):
    return range(number)
` I have written this . but it shows AttributeError at /

'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:  1.8
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: That should be in an other question